# nuxeo oracle database connection

Tags: oracle11g, nuxeo

I have 2 instance for 1 DataBase. While configuring in DB name nuxeo is not accepting DB name and it is taking instance_name. Can you please suggest how can i use database name only. Or is there any other solution around.

Regards,
Nuxeo user

Answer (score 0):

Nuxeo database parameters for Oracle are used to generate the following jDBC URL: `nuxeo.db.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:${nuxeo.db.user}/${nuxeo.db.password}@${nuxeo.db.host}:${nuxeo.db.port}:${nuxeo.db.name}`.
What would you expect?

Note that you can still create your own database configuration template to override the generated configuration files with your own, properly configured.

Comment: {nuxeo.db.name} is accepting instance name not the database name.